# How to perform aggregate function two times with two different criteria to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I like to use igraph to display relation ship between Switch and the Impacted Networks as a result of problem with the switch. Since there are lots of incidents, I would like to show the top 10 switches are that most problematic and as a result impacted Networks.

df

```
Incident    Date        Switch ImpactedNetwork
123        1/1/2012       A     Wireless
455        1/2/2012       B     LocalLan
460        1/3/2012       A     LocalLan
465        1/4/2012       A     Production
```

etc

to assing 1 everytime an incident happens with a swithc:

```
df$count<-c(1)
```

To come up with the top 10 most problematic switches:

```
library(data.table)
df<-df[, total := sum(count), by = Switch]
```

df

```
Incident    Date        Switch ImpactedNetwork  count   Total
123        1/1/2012       A     Wireless         1        3
455        1/2/2012       B     LocalLan         1        1
460        1/3/2012       A     LocalLan         1        3
465        1/4/2012       A     Production       1        3
```

from this df, how do I get the top 10 highest incident based on Total?

Once I determine, the top ten switches, I need aggregate count of ImpactedNetwork for the top then problematic switch.

```
t<-aggregate(count~ImpactedNetwork+Switch, df, sum)
```

t

```
ImpactedNework   Switch   count
Production       A         1
Wireless         A         1

plot(t, layout = layout.kamada.kawai,  vertex.label = V(g)$name,  vertex.label.color= "darkblue",  edge.arrow.size=0.9,  edge.curved=T, edge.label=t$count, edge.label.color="#F900F9", edge.label.font=10,vertex.shape="rectangle",edge.color="darkgreen", main="Top 10 Problematic Switches and Impacted Network"))
```

The ideas is this:

1. calculate the most incident generated switches
2. calculate count of impacted network give the Switch
   3.Igraph the the result.

Should I do this in two separate data frames to first calculate the most incident generated switches? And, anthor data frame to calucate the count of impacted network? Any ideas is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[,Total:=sum(count),by=Switch][head(order(-Total),10)][ ... etc ... ]
```